# How can I stop text from overlapping when a transition takes place

Tags: css, flexbox, hover, css-transitions, overlap

I have two paragraphs of elements on the same line. When the container gets too small to fit both of them, the first paragraph starts to become an ellipsis. I also have a check mark that slides in from the right on hover. The problem is that when I apply this slide-in transition, the second paragraph overlaps the first instead of it becoming an ellipsis. What can I do to fix this behaviour?

Here's a link to the code: https://jsfiddle.net/L47kx6fe/6/

And this is what I'm looking to create: https://giphy.com/gifs/KzDopDzjZeJGV0pxTX

```css
.menu-item {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 10px 20px 10px 10px;
  margin: 0px 10px;
  gap: 3px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 1px lightgray;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.fa-check {
  box-sizing: content-box;
  padding: 7.5px 6px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: white;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #99E2D0;
}

.menu-item:hover .fa-check {
  transform: rotate(360deg);
  transition: transform 800ms ease;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

.item-price {
  transition: 1s ease;
}

.menu-item:hover .item-price {
  transform: translateX(-65px);
  transition: transform 1s ease;
}

.order-check {
  width: 65px;
  height: 100%;
  background: #99E2D0;
  border-top-right-radius: 10px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  transform: translateX(65px);
  transition: transform 1s ease;
}

.menu-item:hover .order-check {
  transform: translateX(0px);
  transition: transform 1s ease;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

.menu-details {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

.menu-desc {
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.bold {
  font-weight: bold;
}

.small-font {
  font-size: 13px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/06b1522f9a.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div class="menu-item">
  <div class="order-check">
    <i class="fa-solid fa-check fa-fw"></i>
  </div>
  <p class="bold">Duck Foie Gras</p>
  <div class="menu-details">
    <p class="small-font menu-desc">This text is overlapped by the price on transition but I want it to become an ellipsis</p>
    <p class="bold small-font item-price">35€</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The element is absolutely positioned, so it does not affect the positioning of other element. You will have to reduce the width of the actual content at the same time here, I think.

Comment: Yes, @Cbroe is right. See my answer below.

Comment: @CBroe Ah okay. I understand now why the check box is overlapping, but .item-price isn't positioned absolutely, so why does it overlap as well?

Comment: @RokBenko Thanks for your answer! I've tried something similar already and it almost gives me the outcome I'm looking for but it's not 100%. I have a video of the effect I'm hoping to achieve but I'm not sure how/if I can send it on here.

Comment: @Rob You can edit your question and add a GIF.

Comment: _"but .item-price isn't positioned absolutely, so why does it overlap as well?"_ - I am talking about how your `.order-check` is absolutely positioned, so _that one_ does not influence the position or dimension of other elements. And because it doesn't it will overlap all the rest to the left of it, when you translate it into that direction.

Comment: @Cbroe Yeah I understand that .order-check is positioned absolutely and there will overlap other elements. To counteract this I’ve applied the same transition as .order-check to .item-price giving the illusion that .order-check is pushing .item-price aside. What I don’t understand is why .item-price , which isn’t positioned absolutely, is also overlapping .menu-desc. Apologies if I’m missing something here

Comment: @RokBenko I’ve added a link to the gif of what I’m trying to create.

Answer (score 0):

setting transition at the menu-details. not item-price.

```css
.menu-item {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 10px 20px 10px 10px;
  margin: 0px 10px;
  gap: 3px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 1px lightgray;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.fa-check {
  box-sizing: content-box;
  padding: 7.5px 6px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: white;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #99E2D0;
}

.menu-item:hover .fa-check {
  transform: rotate(360deg);
  transition: transform 800ms ease;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

.order-check {
  width: 65px;
  height: 100%;
  background: #99E2D0;
  border-top-right-radius: 10px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  transform: translateX(65px);
  transition: transform 1s ease;
}

.menu-item:hover .order-check {
  transform: translateX(0px);
  transition: transform 1s ease;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

.menu-details {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  transition: 1s ease;
  width: 100%;
}

.menu-item:hover .menu-details {
  width: calc(100% - 65px);
}

.menu-desc {
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.bold {
  font-weight: bold;
}

.small-font {
  font-size: 13px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/06b1522f9a.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div class="menu-item">
  <div class="order-check">
    <i class="fa-solid fa-check fa-fw"></i>
  </div>
  <p class="bold">Duck Foie Gras</p>
  <div class="menu-details">
    <p class="small-font menu-desc">This text is overlapped by the price on transition but I want it to become an ellipsis text text text text text text text text text text text</p>
    <p class="bold small-font item-price">35€</p>
  </div>
</div>
```